# PlantUml define relative position of components

Tags: plantuml

I'm actually trying to generate a component diagram with `PlantUml`. Is it possible to define the relative position of the different components? What I want to define is: ComponentB is left from ComponentA. ComponentC is below ComponentA, ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to align blocks in PlantUML class diagrams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11557426/how-to-align-blocks-in-plantuml-class-diagrams)

Answer (score 112, accepted):

A typical approach is to mark a line as [hidden](http://plantuml.com/class-diagram#27).

One thing to keep in mind is that `hidden` is only supported for left-to-right `->`, and top-to-bottom `-->` lines, so you need to place the left and right side accordingly (syntax `X <[hidden]- Y` doesn't seem to be supported).

```
@startuml
class ComponentA

ComponentB -[hidden]> ComponentA
ComponentA -[hidden]-> ComponentC
@enduml
```

[image]

See also [How to correct PlantUML Line Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48712801/how-to-correct-plantuml-line-path/48735216#48735216) for more positioning tips.

Comment: >is only supported for left-to-right ->, and top-to-bottom --> lines

TIL. That functionality isn't mentioned in the documentation!

Comment: @campisano has mentioned a link in above comment. Which has information on, using *together* keyword to group some classes together : the layout engine will try to group them (as if they were in the same package).

Answer (score 58):

You can follow guidelines from here:
[Layout of grouping component](https://forum.plantuml.net/1628/layout-of-grouping-component)

In general when you write connections like -> you just have to know that there is special notation for right arrow, left arrow, bottom arrow, top arrow:
This has special meaning for plantUml:

```
 -l->
 -r->
 -u->
 -d->
```

It means to place arrow on the left or right or up or down if possible.

Lets imagine this diagram:

```
@startuml
node "My system" {
  [A] -> [B]
  [C] -> [B]
}
@enduml
```

[image: Not good placement]

This looks horrible, you can fix this by directing PlanUml with arrow directions.

```
@startuml
node "My system" {
  [A] -d-> [B]
  [C] -r-> [B]
}
@enduml
```

Will generate this:

[image: Good placement]

Comment: Why is this not the accepted answer this is perfect, unless you can't combine `[hidden]` and `-u|d|l|r->`

Comment: You can combine those. But it's finicky (as everything in organizing PlantUML states seems to be). `STATE0 -up[hidden]-> STATE1: TEST` does work but may be different with only one `-` as `STATE0 -up[hidden]> STATE1: TEST`.

Comment: `-[hidden]right->` seems valid, but does not do what I want yet..