# How to correct PlantUML Line Path

Tags: uml, graphviz, diagram, sequence-diagram, plantuml

I created this diagram using the following code. But as you can see, the lines going from (Cancel Order) and (Place Order) to (Publisher) decide to take a terribly rounded path to get their, instead of going straight to the right and then down to publisher. I tried using manual direction commands like "-down" but none of them seemed to help. Does anybody know how to fix this?

[image]

And here is my code. I appreciate any help. Thank you.

```
@startUML EBook Use Case Diagram
left to right direction
Actor Customer as customer
Actor EBook as ebook
Actor Publisher as publisher
rectangle "Book Catalogue" {
    together {
        Actor "Book Database" as bookLog
        (Retrieve Information) as getBook
        customer -- getBook
        getBook -- ebook
        getBook -- bookLog

        (Update Catalogue) as updateCatalogue
        ebook -- updateCatalogue
        updateCatalogue -- bookLog
    }

    together {
        (Place Order) as order
        customer -- order
        order -- ebook
        order--publisher

        (Cancel Order) as cancelOrder
        customer -- cancelOrder
        cancelOrder -- ebook
        cancelOrder--publisher
    }
}

(Ship To EBook) as shipEBook
shipEBook -- publisher
(Ship To Customer) as shipCustomer
customer -- shipCustomer
ebook -- shipEBook
shipCustomer -- ebook

(Return to EBook) as returnCustomer
(Returnto Publisher) as returnPublisher
customer -- returnCustomer
returnCustomer -- ebook
ebook -- returnPublisher
returnPublisher -- publisher

@endUML
```

Comment: how do you make the picture so clear?  did you first export to svg and then convert to png?

Comment: hey, I just did export to image (png probably?) with the vscode plant uml extension. I don't use vscode or plantuml anymore, so I can't be of much help, sorry.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To make a connection less important in the layout, use `[norank]`, e.g., `a -[norank]-> b`

Comment: My goal with this answer is to document an undocumented PlantUML feature with minimal cognitive load in a place where related features are nicely listed (and accepted as the answer). Users of PlantUML will appreciate `norank` in the context of this question.

Answer (score 68):

There are some tricks that you can try, listed below. The layouting itself is performed by GraphViz (dot layouting iirc), and GraphViz simply does this sometimes. Graph layouting is a NP-complete problem, so algorithms usually take harsh shortcuts.

Typical workarounds that I've seen or used include:

- adding hidden lines `a -[hidden]- b`
- extending the length of a line `a --- b` (more dashes, longer line)
- specifying preferred direction of lines (`a -left- b`)
- swapping association ends (`a -- b` → `b -- a`)
- changing the order of definitions (the order *does* matter... sometimes)
- adding empty nodes with background/border colors set to Transparent

So if you really want to have a nice layout, you'll need to put some elbow grease in, but keep in mind that the layout will be still brittle -- if you add/remove items, you might need to redo it again.

Comment: I would like to point out the use of `together` done by @aSamWow. I didn't know this command before but I just successfully use it like following : `together group1 { class a
class b } 
together group2 {
 class c 
class d } 
group1 -[hidden]- group2`

Answer (score 51):

Try the options suggested by @Peter Uhnak along with linetype :

```
skinparam linetype polyline
skinparam linetype ortho
```

Give better options for lines. 
Using ortho - ([Here](http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/TLJBRiCW4Bpp5QkSqeF_8QtRGwLAYVhu069lR1GC5bvNggh-UrcmmSw34pixExCBsBk1fAEnqs8uAzDB9plGoY3zz0ZMKMk5nXC1MN2gQGbgvR0YPOruhCWwACU1R8SEv03Lj9zIBq_MdXd7ezzCu64yQZMqiQ2V0y6YqZGQOHEgIabIssR43VmAy8jiWyHbCUGL1IF_sVEFSl1qByjsRxP9nEqxabFuZV1gJjPralj_OARNvFB4d2U0ehZAJJ6dua0t4hDpjlxgQqcOvmcsOm0JbjX1btNk4IxmfIMd_yIzizeUjAmGzgv65rgmlBivzpeJekkP0rmK-GApKobDXNfXLGLWVzVmPZvZr-QBvBA5U0B-3BOVhUhXqyON67eOF18YaNQicujJpVoWKzaCY6NFgqIwjhLBkU370GI_nD4P_fnoRovWIMtYU4hwLXQqXAtQkP1OXza_DNgfTH6lZsQ7flP_Y7y0))

you will get -

[image]

Comment: Good idea, it does fix the problem, but Ortho lines mess up labels in plant UML so I try to avoid them for more complex diagrams.

Comment: "label positioning wrong in linetype ortho" - please vote for it: https://github.com/plantuml/plantuml/issues/149

Answer (score 21):

If anyone wants to know a more specific, put probably much more useless answer, here is what I did in the end.

```
    order -down- publisher
    publisher -[hidden]up- order
```

so for some reason adding the duplicated command both ways solves it.

Comment: > for some reason:    I guess the reason is that every edge adds weight. In Graphviz one can specify weight of edges, but I have not found a way to do it in PlantUML.

Answer (score 4):

All these good answers are compiled and referenced in the semi-official [Hitchhiker’s Guide to PlantUML](https://crashedmind.github.io/PlantUMLHitchhikersGuide/index.html). See the [Layout section](https://crashedmind.github.io/PlantUMLHitchhikersGuide/layout/layout.html).

Not sure how it was 3 years ago, but it's probably now a better starting point for PlantUML tweaks than SO.