# PlantUML: how to sort items? ... and grouping

Tags: layout, uml, plantuml

I am not sure about how to sort components in PlantUML.
From this code:

```
@startuml
package "TEMP" {
    component [A 1] as A1
    component [A 2] as A2
    component [A 3] as A3
    component [A 4] as A4
    component [A 5] as A5
    component [A 6] as A6

    A1 -[hidden]- A4
    A2 -[hidden]- A5
    A3 -[hidden]- A6
}
@enduml
```

I get:

```
A3 A2 A1
A6 A5 A4
```

If I flip A3, A2 and A1 only, I get:

```
A1 A2 A3
A4 A5 A6
```

i.e., also A6, A5 and A4 are flipped.

Is this normal behavior?
Is PlantUML normal behavior to flip the order of the components, so that I have to invert them?

Below, I use the `-[hidden]-` token to group the objects as I want. Is this the correct approach?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PlantUml define relative position of components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45103284/plantuml-define-relative-position-of-components)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48712801/how-to-correct-plantuml-line-path?answertab=votes#tab-top for more layouting tricks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, just leave it as

```
package "TEMP" {
    component [A 1] as A1
    component [A 2] as A2
    component [A 3] as A3
    component [A 4] as A4
    component [A 5] as A5
    component [A 6] as A6
}
```

or specify relative positions for all

```
package "TEMP" {
    component [A 1] as A1
    component [A 2] as A2
    component [A 3] as A3
    component [A 4] as A4
    component [A 5] as A5
    component [A 6] as A6

    A1 -[hidden]> A2
    A2 -[hidden]> A3

    A1 -[hidden]-> A4
    A2 -[hidden]-> A5
    A3 -[hidden]-> A6
}
```

Both generate the same

[image]

[image]